# Using Map3 and Engine in the same project?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

Correct me if I'm wrong, but looks like I will have troubles if I try to use Map3 and Engine in the same project due the same package names? 
Is there any way it can be done?

PS Side note - looks like Engine master branch (at least 'demo' module) cannot be compiled right now due to dependencies issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, open source version of Chronicle Engine depends on Chronicle Map 2 (and supports only Chronicle Map 2) which uses the same package names as Chronicle Map 3, so they might not work together without shading/package renaming, even if you use Chronicle Map 3 and Chronicle Engine separately, i. e. not doing replication or remote calls to Chronicle Map 3.

There is a Chronicle Engine version which supports Chronicle Map 3, but it is closed source, visit http://chronicle.software for details.